# SQL Query to return only one row when id is found in multiple rows from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I'm new to SQL and I have an issue that may seem simple, but I don't know what to do.

I have two tables, one for payments, one for certificates.
I want to return all certificates that fulfill the condition that their public_key is present in an unpaid row inside the payment table. I tried using join, but it would return all the payment requests when I just want the certificates.

Here is the payment table:
[image]

Here is the certificate table:
[image]

And here is what I tried with JOIN:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM certificate
  WHERE created_at BETWEEN '${beginDate}' AND '${endDate}'
  LEFT JOIN payment ON certificate.public_key = payment.certificate_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to return all certificates that fulfill the condition that their public_key is present in an unpaid row inside the payment table.

If I followed you correctly, you can use `exists`:

```
select c.*
from certificate c
where exists (
    select 1
    from payment p
    where 
        p.certificate_id = c.public_key
        and created_at BETWEEN :beginDate AND :endDate
        and p.status = 'unpaid'
)
```

Note that, based on your problem description, I added a filtering criteria on `payment(status)`.

The upside of this approach is that it does not duplicate the `certificate` rows if there is one more than one matching "unpaid" row in the `payment` table.

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to return all certificates that fulfill the condition that their public_key is present in an unpaid row inside the payment table.

That would suggest something like this:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM certificate c JOIN
     payment p
     ON c.public_key = p.certificate_id;
WHERE c.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

An outer join isn't necessary and the `JOIN` is an *operator* in the `FROM` clause.